# Submit button not posting on modal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form on a bootstrap modal with two buttons.  This form is tied to an action named "DeleteWidgetConfirmed" I am trying to remove a widget from the database and from the front end, the panel gets removed from the front end but does not seem to get removed from the database.

Here is my Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteWidgetModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete widget?</h4><!--add depending on which panel you have clicked-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
            <!--Depending on which panel insert content-->
            @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteWidgetConfirmed", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                Do you wish to delete this widget?

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="DeleteWidgetConfirmed" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" id="delete-widget">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my action:

```
// POST: DashboardModels/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteWidgetConfirmed(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        DashboardModel dashboardModel = db.dashboards.Find(id);
        db.dashboards.Remove(dashboardModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

From my javascript I get the ID from the panel and store it into a variable,  I then get the action attribute from my form and append the ID to the action attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#columns').on('click', '.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash', function (event) {
    var panel = this;
    //get id here

    //toggle the modal
    $('#deleteWidgetModal').modal('show');
    var widgetID = $(this).closest('.panel.panel-default').attr('data-widgetid');

    document.getElementById('delete-widget').onclick = function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        //we make an ajax call to the controller on click
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Dashboard", "DeleteWidgetConfirmed"))',
            data: { id: widgetID},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(data){
                var parentElement = $(panel).closest(".col-md-4.column");
                var targetElement = $(panel).closest(".panel.panel-default");
                targetElement.remove();

                //parentElement.addClass("expand-panel");
                checkEmptyPanelContainers();
                $('#deleteWidgetModal').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        })           
    }
})
```

});

I have a hunch that maybe within my javascript I have overridden the default behaviour of the event.

What I want to achieve ultimately is

1. within the onclick event for the button to remove the panels(which works)
2. remove the entry within the database related to that panel.
3. When executing the post method do not refresh.

Comment: What is the *value* sent in the HTTP Request itself? My first guess is it is not correctly extracted to the `widgetID` variable - possibly because the data-attribute is not assigned when it is first read (or assigned at all!). This could cause an *error* which is handled differently than success which would bypass the 'refresh' logic. Again, this will be readily apparent by looking at the Network Access in the browser..

Comment: @user2864740  I stepped through the javascript code and hovered over the WidgetID, it comes back as 6 which is correct so it is getting the widgetID correctly.  It now comes back with a BadRequest specified in the controller method

Comment: So look at the HTTP Request and Controller/action and find out why it is "bad". There is any point worry about anything else until that is resolved.

Comment: Just looked at the HTTP rrequest and it doesn't seem to pass through the widget ID.  I think you may be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AJAX to asynchronously post to your controller:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#columns').on('click', '.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash', function (event) {
        var panel = this;
        //get id here

        //toggle the modal
        $('#deleteWidgetModal').modal('toggle');
        var widgetID = $(this).closest('.panel.panel-default').attr('data-widgetid');

        $.ajax({
             url: '/Dashboard/DeleteWidgetConfirmed/',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { id: widgetid },
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             error: function (xhr) {
                // request failed, handle here!
             },
             success: function (result) {
                // request succeeded! handle that here. close the modal? remove the item from the UI?
             }
          });
        }
    });
});
```

How you handle the success callback depends on the UI, you can use the data- attributes to do so quite easily.

You need to decorate your action method as POST if you do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteWidgetConfirmed(int id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, it hits the controller method ok however it does not seem to want to pass through the ID, my controller says it is null, I know this because I added some extra functionality into it to check for null, I changed the parameter in my controller to a nullable int and returned a badrequest if it is null.  I will update my code so you understand better

Comment: I have also stepped through my javascript code in firebug and widgetID is definitely 6

Comment: You'll have to put the ID in the row somehow and change the code I used to retrieve it to grab it. I was going to update the code to do this but it is referencing something with an ID called columns that isnt in your view code.

Comment: Hi @br4d I have fixed this now I also had to add RequestVerificationToken into the data attribute of the ajax call